# build is not defined in Notification.Builder

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-notifications

I have the following code and its giving me 'build() is not defined in Notification.Builder' error.

```
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mApplicationContext)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setContent(mContentView)
                            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
                            .setAutoCancel(true);                   

// Send the notification
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mParentActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

In the manifest file, the minSdk is 13 and targetSdk is 19. The directory had no lib folder, I created one and added android-support-v4.jar file in it. Still its giving me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are targeting API 19 and min API 13 (HC), you need to use NotificationCompat.Builder - try:

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    mApplicationContext);
  Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContent(mContentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).build();
// Send the notification
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mParentActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: I changed the minSdk version to 19 and also compiled it with 19 and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Change minSdkVersion to 19. Also change its properties to compile it with API level 19 and it will work.  Use AVD with at least minSdkVersion. I would recommend using whatever the tragetVersion is